# AWS, Angular on S3 Bucket, Spring boot on ec2 instance (created with Elastic Beanstalk) and Load Balancer

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-elb

I have a web app, angular frontend hosted on a bucket s3 and spring boot backend hosted in an ec2 instance with elastic beanstalk.
When I include an Elastic Load Balancer I got a CORS error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url of Elastic Load balancer' from origin 'url of angular frontend' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I just set in s3 bucket a CORS policy like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

and in my backend I did a configuration class like this

```
@Configuration
public class FiltersCorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer()
    {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer()
        {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)
            {
                registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("PUT","DELETE","GET","POST","OPTIONS","HEAD","PATCH")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("header1","header2","Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .maxAge(3600);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?!

Comment: are you using CloudFront to route traffic to your bucket?

Comment: @MillerC nope!!

Comment: I believe CloudFront is recommended with hosting a static app from an S3 bucket and CF has the CORS stuff and documentation to get it working... I'm not sure without CF though sorry. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes, I can try.. also It is impossible that there is not a solution!